# ¿Porque sucede este error dentro de este constructor? (JAVA)

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo programación Java, ya estoy comenzando con programación orientada a objetos, y al estar revisando un código de un examen me surgió una duda que no he podido encontrar porqué sucede.

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
class Vehicle{

int x;

Vehicle(){

    this(10);
}

Vehicle(int x){
    this.x=x;
}

}
```

y esta otra que hereda de la clase anterior:

```
class Car extends Vehicle{
int y;

Car(){

    super();
    this(20);//line 1
}

Car(int y){
    this.y=y;
}

public String toString(){
    return super.x+" : "+this.y;
}

}
```

En la clase `Car` dentro del constructor me da un error de compilación (line 1) diciendo `call to this must be first statement in constructor` ya lo cambie de linea y al hacerlo marca el mismo error en `super()`.

Encontré una solución pero tengo curiosidad de saber porque ocurre ese error.
Agradezco mucho por compartir su experiencia.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Solo para que no te respondan algo que ya sabes, podes poner la solucion que encontraste?

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS POR  LA AYUDA!!! : )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this()` y `super()` son incompatibles.

Al instanciar una clase, si no pones nada especial (ni `this()` ni `super()`), lo primero que hace tu constructor es llamar al constructor de la superclase inmediata (que a su vez llama al constructor de su superclase inmediata, así hasta llegar a `Object()`). Si no se especifica otra cosa, se llama al constructor por defecto (sin parámetros) de la superclase.

Si quieres especificar el constructor de la superclase que se invoca haces `super([parámetros])` **como la primera instrucción** (como hemos dicho antes, es lo primero que se hace al ejecutar el constructor).

Otra forma de verlo es que si no pones nada, hay un `super();` implícito.

Cuando pones `this()` **como primera instrucción**, lo que haces es invocar a otro constructor de la misma clase, y *será ese constructor el que decida a qué constructor de la superclase llamar* (explícita o implícitamente).

Si haces

```
Car(){
  super();
  this(20);
}
```

primero llamas a `Vehicle()` (que invoca implícitamente a `Object()`), y luego invocas a `Car(int)`. Y `Car(int)` a su vez invoca a `Vehicle(int)` que también invoca a `Object()`.

Si haces

```
Car(){
  this(20);
  super();
}
```

primero llamas a `Car(int)` que a su vez invoca a `Vehicle(int)`, y luego a `Vehicle()`.

Para evitar esta situación, basta con seguir las reglas.

- Si haces un `super()` explícito, debe ser la primera instrucción del constructor.
- Si haces un `this()`, debe ser la primera instrucción del constructor.

Como solo puedes tener una primera instrucción del constructor, no se pueden combinar ambos.

Resumen, poniendo una etiqueta a cada constructor (el constructor `Object()` es `Z`)

```
class Vehicle{

  Vehicle(){ // A
    this(10);
  }

  Vehicle(int x){ //B
  }
}

class Car extends Vehicle{

  Car(){  // C
    super();
  }

  Car(String s) { // D
     this(10);
  }

  Car(int i) {  // E
  }
}
```

- Invocando C: C -> A -> B -> Z
- Invocando D: D -> E -> A -> B -> Z
- Invocando E: E -> A -> B -> Z

Un ejercicio útil es poner un `System.out.println` en cada constructor para ver el flujo de ejecución.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y te felicito, tu explicación es a detalle, muy comprensible. Saludos!!