# llamar a un constructor desde otro constructor en java

Tags: java, constructor

para un ejercicio de practica tengo dos constructores para crear una tabla, en uno de ellos recibo como argumentos una matriz con los datos y un vector con los encabezados, yo quiero insertar en la matriz los encabezados para luego enviar la matriz editada al constructor final, pero me informaron que no puedo colocar logica en el constructor, asi que saque el proceso aparte en un método el cual edita la matriz y la retorna para enviarla al constructor final pero igual me da error, no se en que estoy mal y que me pueden recomendar hacer ?

```
public Tabla(String [][]matriz){
    filas=matriz.length; //devuelve cantidad de filas en la matriz
    columnas=matriz[0].length; //devuelve cantidad de datos enesa fila
    m=new String[filas][columnas];
    m=matriz;
    m2=new String[filas][columnas];
    m2=matriz;  //uso m2 para cuando se necesite girar la tabla
    bordeH="";
    bordeV="|";
    tabla="";
    anchoColumna=new int[columnas]; //dimensiona segun cantidad decolumnas
    anchoFila=new int[filas];
    anchoTabla=0;
}
public Tabla(String [][] matriz, String[]encabezado){
    Tabla(unirMatriz(matriz,encabezado));
}
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Porque sucede este error dentro de este constructor? (JAVA)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194964/porque-sucede-este-error-dentro-de-este-constructor-java)

Comment: Hola alf! Bienvenido a [es.so] recomendamos que hagas el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas, también es interesante echar un vistazo a [ask] donde verás cosas como por ejemplo que el código siempre tiene que estar en formato de texto y no como imagen. Ya que si alguien quiere copiar y pegar para hacer pruebas, en formato imagen es muy tedioso tener que escribir todo. Un saludo!

Comment: edito  mi pregunta añadiendo el código en texto  :)

Answer (score 1):

para llamar al primer constructor debes de utilizar la palabra reservada this.
De tal manera que si llamamos al segundo constructor como te pongo en el ejemplo. Crea una instancia del primer constructor.
Para comprobarlo he puesto estas lineas en el primer constructor:

```
System.out.println(">>>> estamos en constructor 1");
System.out.println(">>>> salimos del constructor 1");
```

Esta seria la salida por consola:

```
run:
>>>> estamos en constructor 1
>>>> salimos del constructor 1
Filas >>>> 9
Columnas >>>> 9
Tablas unidas
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Esta seria la clase main:

```
public class StackOverFlow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] matriz = new String[9][9];
        String[] encabezado = new String[9];

        Tabla tabla = new Tabla(matriz,encabezado);
    }

}
```

Para comprobar que la llamada metodo funciona, comprobamos que las variables se han instanciado bien, sacando su longitud por consola:

```
public class Tabla {
    private int filas;
    private int columnas;
    private String[][] m;
    private String[][] m2;
    private String bordeH;
    private String bordeV;
    private String tabla;
    private int[] anchoColumna; 
    private int[] anchoFila;
    private int anchoTabla;
    private String[] encabezado;

    public Tabla(String [][]matriz){
        System.out.println(">>>> estamos en constructor 1");
        filas=matriz.length; //devuelve cantidad de filas en la matriz
        columnas=matriz[0].length; //devuelve cantidad de datos enesa fila
        m = new String[filas][columnas];
        m = matriz;
        m2 = new String[filas][columnas];
        m2=matriz;  //uso m2 para cuando se necesite girar la tabla
        bordeH="";
        bordeV="|";
        tabla="";
        anchoColumna=new int[columnas]; //dimensiona segun cantidad decolumnas
        anchoFila=new int[filas];
        anchoTabla=0;
        System.out.println(">>>> salimos del constructor 1");
    }

    public Tabla(String [][] matriz, String[]encabezado){
        this(matriz);
        unirMatriz(matriz, encabezado);

    }

    public void unirMatriz(String [][] matriz,String[]encabezado){
        System.out.println("Filas >>>> "+filas);
        System.out.println("Columnas >>>> "+columnas);
        System.out.println("Tablas unidas");
    } 
}
```

Comment: pero lo que yo queria era unir la matriz con los encabezados primero y luego enviarlo al constructor final para que por ej el constructor final tome que son 9 filas y 10 columnas (incluyendo la nueva columna encabezado), pero según pude leer de otros post la llamada al constructor debe ser la primera línea como tu lo indicas en el ejemplo (asi que no se si se pueda como yo queria hacerlo). 
Tomare tu ejemplo y al final dentro del segundo constructor reasignare los valores de columnas, matriz, entre otros que se deban modificar al agregar el encabezado. 
Sin más que decir GRacias :)

Comment: Por favor si puedes poner el codigo completo, y el enunciado del ejercicio, gracias.